# How Jsonwebtoken save token in header in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, json-web-token

1.
I am new in jsonwebtoken in node.js express.I am using jsonwebtoken to create token and everything is cleared from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-web-token

I have only one doubt after creating the token then how do they save token in header.?

2.When are we using the jsonwebtoken then is it necessary to use passport.js local ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will start from the end

> 2.When are we using the jsonwebtoken then is it necessary to use passport.js local ?

No, `jwt` is separate tool which can work without `passport.js` , you can find that other languages and platforms can use `jwt`  in their applications too.
this is just HTTP [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) which helps create RESTful applications with authentication or with other purposes.

> I have only one doubt after creating the token then how do they save token in header.?

you can save `jwt` token in your cookies.
simply add this to your route of express applications

```
res.cookie('token', jwt)
```

and this will add cookies to your headers cookies, and you can have access to your token on browser.

I would suggest you to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package instead for managing `jwt` tokens

Comment: You mean i should not use passport right when using local strategy ?

Comment: Do you also know how to encrypt the payloader in jwt ?

Comment: Hi, you read npmjs documentation for `jsonwebtoken` module,
It says that you can encrypt it with `decode` method which won't check validity,but will just show data and this is not useful for auth, and `verify` method which will look at secret key too and this is used for auth, so do this `jwt.verify(token, secret)` and this will check validity for your token.
fell free to use `password.js`, I just said that it is not necessary for `jwt` and you can create valid programs without it!

Answer (score 0):

Then you'll need to verify the token which came from client to server. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt for that.